# State of MPE in AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

I'm working with a Linnstrument and am very excited to write some custom AudioKit synths for it.
To this end, what is the state of MPE in AudioKit currently? From what I've read it seems to be on some road maps but I'd love to learn more. Perhaps I could even help.

Tried AudioKit apps with MPE enabled but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: MPE should be explained as MIDI polyphonic expression. The question is not about programming but about the project status and roadmap of an opensource library.